# dash app dependencies for deployment on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, plotly-dash

I'm working on deploying my first dash app via heroku. I already did the example deployment given here: https://dash.plotly.com/deployment

which was quick and easy. Now I'm running through the same process with my own dash app, which is much more involved than the example app in the link, but which runs fine locally.

In step 2 given in the link, you initialize an empty git repo and run a new virtualenv, okay. Then you have to reinstall all the **app's dependencies** into the new virtual env.

This is my question, what are my app dependencies? Are those the modules I install at the top of my apps .py file? such as pandas, numpy, sklearn, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's correct. They must be defined in the `requirements.txt` file in the root of your project.

You can create the file manually or running this command

```
 pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

The file looks something like this

```
pandas==1.2.0
numpy==1.19.4
```

Comment: Do I need to install them manually in the virtualenv, as I did in the first example? or is it enough to have them in the requirements.txt file?

Comment: It is enough to add them in the requirements.txt, Heroku will use that to install the packages

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the help

Comment: One more question. I have 3 csv files that my app needs to call, all I do is upload them to the git repo with the rest of the files right?

Comment: Yes, if you dont need to update them (ie readonly)

Comment: Hey, I'm having trouble using the pip freeze command. How should I direct the command to the app file? I currently have the file in the git repo, and am working out of that directory.

Comment: The command in my answer works on Mac (and surely on linux), just run from the terminal in the root of your project. Maybe you are in Windows? In this case you can create the file manually (or try PowerShell)